# Randomization in Silenium

Tags: python, selenium

im using selenium and lets say I wanted to choose a random element right in a  specific class right. How would I do that. Here is an example of my code

```
answer_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="item"]').click()
```

there are multiple items in this class and I want to choose a random one, how would I do so. Sorry if this makes it complicated

Comment: If there are multiple items in the class, first get all the elements: Eg: `answer_click = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="item"]')`. Now if this collection of elements have multiple elements, they would be stored in the list `answer_click`. Use `import random` and then `random.choice(answer_click).click()`. This might work.

Answer (score 2):

This example looks for all the answers, then finds all the visible elements, and eventually gets a random item.

Visibility checking can be removed, but commonly some not visible elements might be found, so the random will be invisible, and click will cause an exception.

```py
import random

all_answers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="item"]')
visible_answers = filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed(), all_answers)
answer_to_click = random.choice(visible_answers)
answer_to_click.click()
```